# How to aggregate a column for a period of one year on each date in year month level (SQL)

Tags: sql-server, date, apache-spark-sql, aggregate

To aggregate the amount column from given date to next one year on each id and date in year month level

Example:

for first row id=1, date=2018-10-01

so get the records from 2018-10-01 to 2019-10-31(next year) and sum the amount, give the o/p in year month level for each id and date

### Input table:

| id | date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-10-01 | 2 |
| 1 | 2018-10-25 | 0 |
| 1 | 2018-11-05 | 1 |
| 1 | 2018-12-24 | 0 |
| 1 | 2019-04-12 | 1 |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 1 |
| 2 | 2012-10-05 | 5 |
| 2 | 2012-11-06 | 4 |

### Required O/P:

| id | yearmonth | sum(amount) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-10 | 4 |
| 1 | 2018-11 | 2 |
| 1 | 2018-12 | 1 |
| 1 | 2019-04 | 2 |
| ... | ....... | ... |
| 2 | 2012-10 | 9 |

First-row sum is from 2018-10-01 to 2019-10-31

Second row sum is from 2018-11-05 to 2019-11-30

and so on

Comment: What happens if you have overlapping dates? And do you need the sum for each id or does that column not matter?

Comment: Yes, I need the sum for each id, and overlapping dates would be there for different id's basically, month and year won't be repeated for the same id in the output. Thank you.